# MySQL can connect to remote through command line, but Laravel fails

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have configured remote MySQL to connect to one database from another server.  When I run MySQL from the command line, it works seamlessly:

```
mysql -u username -p -h 123.12.12.456
```

This gets me right into the remote server.  But when I configure the same DB connection in Laravel, I get

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `table`)

Answer (score 1):

I actually FINALLY got this working right before I posted the question.  Since I couldn't find any other questions like it on stack, I wanted to post anyway and put the answer here:

My `database.php` config file had these 2 lines in the `mysql` config:

```
'strict' => true,
'engine' => null,
```

I removed those and it worked.